# How do I elegantly evaluate a continuous range in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I generate a random number between 0 and 1.  I am probably using the wrong terminology, but I want an elegant way of evaluating the range.

Is there something better than the following?

```
if (RandNum < 0.075) { sVal = 'a'; }
else if (RandNum < 0.123) { sVal = 'b'; }
else if (RandNum < 0.199) { sVal = 'c'; }
... etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
var RandNum = Math.random(),
    letter  = null,
    obj = {
        a : 0.075,
        b : 0.123,
        c : 0.199,
        d : 0.2,
        e : 0.4,
        f : 0.6,
        g : 0.8,
        h : 1
}

for (var k in obj) {
    if (RandNum < obj[k]) {
        letter = k;
        break;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JyJ3M/)

or with two arrays instead

```
var RandNum = Math.random(),
    letters  = 'abcdefgh'.split(''),
    range = [
        0.075,
        0.123,
        0.199,
        0.2,
        0.4,
        0.6,
        0.8,
        1
    ];

while (RandNum < range.pop());
var letter = letters[range.length];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8788/1/)

Comment: Wow... slick and clean.  Perhaps I should stick my head in a broiler and give coding up.

Comment: The 2nd variation is even more impressive, though I suppose the purest would argue about the risk of the two arrays getting out of synch.  In any case, thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, the risk of failure is higher in the first one, which is why I posted the second one. The first one uses an object, and relies on the browser iterating over that object in the order it's written. As there is no guaranteed order in objects, it's not really "safe", but all browsers will iterate in the right order, so it shouldn't be a problem either, it's just that relying on order in something that has no order is usually something we want to avoid.

Comment: @nas - In the second one, there's arrays, and arrays *do* have order, so arrays fit better here. Just note that it changes the original array, so it can only run reliably once, but a simple array copy with slice() fixes that if it's needed.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i can think of would be:

```
switch(true) {
    case (RandNum < 0.075):
        sVal = 'a';
        break;
    case (RandNum < 0.123):
        sVal = 'b';
        break;
    ...
}
```

But it really only changes the looks, javascript has no in-depth function set for floating point operations.

Comment: the repetition is still there, and it's not as easily extensible. @adeneo's answer is much more apropriate.

Comment: could very well be, i don't claim to be of unlimited wisdom, nevertheless, the attitude of your comment is even less appropriate :(

Comment: I am sorry, didn't mean to offend. I have expressed myself incorrectly. *For this case*, where the behaviour of the script is the same, adeneo's answer is appropriate, however, if different behaviour is necessary in each case, the solution would be the `switch` statement indeed.